# How to get aura:id of checkbox from iteration?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am using lightning component to show the list of contacts. I need to get checkbox `aura:id` when form loads but the checkbox is under the iteration loop.

is there anyway to achieve this?

**Note: I want to get `aura:id` of all the checkboxes when form loads, not when event performed.**

**Sample Code**

```
<aura:iteration var="con" items="{!v.conList}">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <lightning:input type="text" disabled="true" value="{!con.Name}"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <lightning:input type="checkbox" 
                                 data-record="{!index}" 
                                 aura:id="doctorId" 
                                 Label="Favourite" 
                                 value="{!con.Id}" 
                                 onchange ="{!c.saveFavourite}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <lightning:input type="text" disabled="true" value="{!con.Speciality__c}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <lightning:input type="text" disabled="true" value="{!con.Region__c}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</aura:iteration>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used this snippet and my problem got resolved.

```
var doctorId= component.get('v.conList');
        
for (var i=0; i<doctorId.length; i++) {
   console.log('checkboxes - ' + doctorId[i].Id);
}
```